# A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Hello I am executing the following code:

```
grid_params_bc = {
        'base_estimator': [best_knn, best_rf, best_l],
        'n_estimators': [10, 20, 50]
    }

    gs_bc = GridSearchCV(
        BaggingClassifier(),
        grid_params_bc,
        cv=10,
        verbose=1,
        n_jobs=-1,
        return_train_score=True,
        scoring='f1_micro'
    )

    clf_bc = gs_bc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated.
> This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the
> function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System
> to kill the worker.

Anyway I could execute the first 34 task of 80.

Why this error is happing?

Thanks

Comment: Will this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54141605/13552470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of your data or the actual classifiers you are using, the best guess is that you are doing too heavy computations on your system. As the error message says, there might be an excessive use of memory.

You are performing a grid search on a `BaggingClassifier` with up to 50 base estimators such as Random Forests (at least that's how it looks like). Since each Random Forest consists of 100 Decision Trees by default, this would e.g. result in training and testing 5000 Decision Trees, just in that instance.

Try to use lower numbers of base estimators `n_estimators` and maybe change the `n_jobs` parameter. You have to try around, but it should resolve the issue.