# GridSearchCV raising SIGABRT(-6) error with n_jobs != 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, anaconda

I'm having this issue both on windows and ubuntu:

```
Fitting 10 folds for each of 12 candidates, totalling 120 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7f45139d8580 state=finished raised TerminatedWorkerError>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 347, in __call__
    self.parallel.dispatch_next()
  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 780, in dispatch_next
    if not self.dispatch_one_batch(self._original_iterator):
  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 847, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 765, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 529, in apply_async
    future = self._workers.submit(SafeFunction(func))
  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/reusable_executor.py", line 177, in submit
    return super(_ReusablePoolExecutor, self).submit(
  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1102, in submit
    raise self._flags.broken
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.

The exit codes of the workers are {SIGABRT(-6)}
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/vhviveiros/GitHub/trabalho_covid/classify.py", line 18, in <module>
    cf.validation(batch_size=[32, 16, 24], epochs=[100, 250, 200, 500])

  File "/home/vhviveiros/GitHub/trabalho_covid/classifier.py", line 67, in validation
    grid_search = grid_search.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 73, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 736, in fit
    self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 1188, in _run_search
    evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 708, in evaluate_candidates
    out = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator),

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1042, in __call__
    self.retrieve()

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 921, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 540, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 347, in __call__
    self.parallel.dispatch_next()

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 780, in dispatch_next
    if not self.dispatch_one_batch(self._original_iterator):

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 847, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 765, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 529, in apply_async
    future = self._workers.submit(SafeFunction(func))

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/reusable_executor.py", line 177, in submit
    return super(_ReusablePoolExecutor, self).submit(

  File "/home/vhviveiros/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1102, in submit
    raise self._flags.broken

TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.

The exit codes of the workers are {SIGABRT(-6)}
```

**What already been done**

- changed intel-openmp version
- reinstalled conda and tf-gpu env
- tried in both windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04
- [How do I fix/debug this Multi-Process terminated worker error thrown in scikit learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139403/how-do-i-fix-debug-this-multi-process-terminated-worker-error-thrown-in-scikit-l)

**OBS:**
When running this code at windows, instead it fills the entire both ram and gpu memory freezing the system. With n_jobs=1, the process used average 2 GB ram (with other parameters). The input file is just a 524x254 .csv.

**Environment: Conda**

- conda 4.8.3
- intel-openmp              2020.1
- scikit-learn              0.23.1
- tensorflow                2.2.0
- tensorflow-base           2.2.0
- tensorflow-estimator      2.2.0
- tensorflow-gpu            2.2.0
- keras                     2.4.3
- keras-base                2.4.3
- keras-preprocessing       1.1.0

**Hardware**

- Ryzen 3600
- 16GB Ram
- RTX 2060 S

**Code example:**

```
validation(batch_size=[32, 16, 24], epochs=[100, 250, 200, 500])
```

**Different file**

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from models import classifier_model
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import datetime
from utils import check_folder
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def validation(self, cv=10, batch_size=-1, epochs=-1):
    classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=classifier_model)

    parameters = {'batch_size': batch_size,
                  'epochs': epochs,
                  'optimizer': ['adam'],
                  'activation': ['relu'],
                  'activationOutput': ['sigmoid']}

    self.metrics = ['accuracy', 'roc_auc', 'precision', 'recall']
    
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier,
                               verbose=2,
                               param_grid=parameters,
                               n_jobs=2,
                               scoring=self.metrics,
                               refit='precision',
                               return_train_score=False,
                               cv=cv)

    grid_search = grid_search.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)

    return grid_search
```

**Different file**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import AUC, Precision, Recall
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

def classifier_model(optimizer, activation, activationOutput):
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units=200, activation=activation, input_shape=(254,)))
    classifier.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=200, activation=activation))
    classifier.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=200, activation=activation))
    classifier.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=200, activation=activation))
    classifier.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=200, activation=activation))
    classifier.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=200, activation=activation))
    classifier.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation=activationOutput))
    classifier.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                       loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', AUC(), Precision(), Recall()])
    return classifier
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by just adding in the model file (3rd example):

```
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

Comment: What is the "model file"? It is not specified in your question. Why does this solve the problem? will it solve this problem for all cases?